# Подстановка в условие if всех индексов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в питоне сделать так, чтобы не проверять каждый индекс отдельно, а проверить все индексы сразу?
Например, есть список

```
a = input().split()
num_list = list(map(int, a))
```

Для того, чтобы проверить первый элемент, надо писать

```
if num_list[0] == 100:
    print(2)
```

А как сделать так, чтобы проверить все элементы? Написать `if num_list[0,1,2,3,4,5] == 100` не получается

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите сделать после проверки, отфильтровать или выполнить конкретное действие по каждому элементу списка, удовлетворяющему условию?

Comment: Выполнить конкретное действие по каждому элементу списка, удовлетворяющему условию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно использовать `filter`

```
a = input().split()
num_list = list(map(int, a))

for x in filter(lambda n:n==100, num_list):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот один из вариантов:

```
a = input().split()
num_list = list(map(int, a))

count = len([x for x in num_list if x > 100])

for i in range(count):
    print(1)

# input: 101 200 1 2 3 
# console: 1 1
```